# fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

Tags: windows, git

После переустановки `git` и начальной настройки глобальных переменных пытаюсь запушить изменения командой:

```
git push origin mybranch
```

получаю ошибку `fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'`

В интернете полно инструкций по решению этой ошибки при клонировании с репозитория, но ни одна мне не подходошла. Я уже пробовал:

1. Переустанавливать git
2. Прописывать переменные `PATH` и даже ставить их в самое начало, что бы не перетирались другими значениями.

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core;

Использую:

ОС - Windows 8.1

Git-2.12.0-64-bit

Comment: Пробовали устанавливать более ранние версии git?

Comment: @Arhad еще не пробовал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло удаление `git` и установка более новой версии (на текущий момент - 2.18.0)